# Can we require_once() in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, model-view-controller, require

Now I code all in php but I hope to enforce MVC model.

So, I prefer to code in javaScript and jquery at front-end.

Only php for call function, API or module.

My question is there any require_once() code in javaScript and Jquery seem like below:

```
begin.php:
<?php
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
?>

end.php:
</body>
</html>

page1.php:
<?php
require_once("begin.php");
<div>
Here is page1.
</div>
require_once("end.php");
?>


page2.php:
<?php
require_once("begin.php");
<div>
Here is page2.
</div>
require_once("end.php");
?>
```

Comment: Both common.js, & ES6 modules are basically require_once by design..

Comment: I'm guessing this is primarily about combining parts of HTML into a full document? That's possible with JS, yes. In fact that's one of the features a frontend framework like React or Vue has: reusable components. However there's a major difference: the page is composed inside the browser, so this will not work for SEO unless you also use server-side-rendering.

Comment: Thank you all. And you provide the tips for me to study.

Comment: I prefer to use the original javascript or jquery to do so as I do not want to increase the study curve and put a lot of language in the project.

My project is running for internal use so SEO is not the main consideration. Thank you.